# How to check if ColumnIndex of an DataGridColumnHeader is the last with Trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Styling DataGrid, I want to differ its last column header by applying trigger to ControlTemplate or Style. For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid>
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" 
                            Content="{Binding}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex" Value="{Binding ???}">

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But to what value I must bind it? There is TemplateBinding, TemplatedParent and many other bindings, but even if I knew which one to use, then again what property I must look for inside it? (well there is obviously some kind of collection with Count or Length property, but it will be good to see exact thing)

With all different bindings that are resolving at runtime, there must be the way to investigate to what type exactly I'm going to bind, right? How can I find it?

Comment: You'll probably need a multiconverter, into which you pass the collection of items (columns) along with the datacontext for this column, then you can check for indexes and return true or false.  Finally, have your trigger check for one of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Children Count` of `DataGridCellsPanel` which is parent of `DataGridColumnHeader` and use a `converter` to check for `LastLevelColumn`

```
   <local:Converter x:Key="myConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Grid x:Name="gridSource">
                        <Grid.Tag>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Children.Count" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}"/>
                                <Binding Path="DisplayIndex"  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Grid.Tag>
                        <Border x:Name="myBorder">
                            <ContentPresenter 
                        DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" 
                        Content="{Binding}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag" SourceName="gridSource" Value="true">
                           <!-- Setter's -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Converter** :

```
  public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is int && values[1] is int)
            return (int)values[0] == (int)values[1] + 1 ? "true" : "false";
        else
            return "false";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```